# Why don't we see any discussion on probability starting with "Continuous outcome" rather than "Continuous r.v."?

Tags: probability, random-variables

When any book starts the discussion of probability, it inevitably starts either with the toss of a coin, or roll of a die. Then the discussion gradually proceeds toward discrete r.v. .

But, I see that, in case of, continuous, the discussion always starts **right from** continuous r.v.

For instance, the following kind of discussion are always missing:

> A cow can produce $5$ to $10$ liters of milk per day.
>
> What is the probability that the cow will produce:
>
> $(1)$ exactly $7.5$ liters of milk next day?
>   $(2)$ at most $7.5$ liters of milk next day?
>   $(3)$ at least $7.5$ liter of milk next day?

Why don't we see any discussion on probability starting with "Continuous outcome" rather than "Continuous r.v."?

Comment: Without assuming that the milk production is a uniformly distributed **random variable**, the questions cannot be answered.

Comment: Perhaps for the reason the answer to your first question is 0?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, in that case, why don't we start with the distribution of *discrete* r.v.? We know that coin toss and rolling dies have normal distributions.

Comment: @RohitPandey, the answer of (1) is already given by myself.